# Accessing registers of esp32 with rust and esp-idf-sys

Tags: rust, camera, embedded, esp32

I am trying to use a OV2640 camera together with ESP32 (TTGo module) and rust. Unfortunately, there is no driver, yet. So, I started to create one. After some digging it seems to me that the I2S module that can be used for camera image read out, has no matching function support from the esp-idf library for this use case. To configure the peripheral, I need to write some register values by hand. For C you can easily find examples for this, e.g. in the esp32-camera library from espressive (see [ll_cam.c, line 256ff.](https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/blob/master/target/esp32/ll_cam.c#L256))

Unfortunately, after looking at the esp-idf-sys and -hal documentation and examples, I could not find any examples or hints how to do that. Also searching on the interwebs didn't bring up anything useful until now.

Maybe it is too obvious...
Can someone give me a hint where to look at or how to do this?

Comment: You should be able to "translate" C code into Rust code. Maybe you'll have more luck if you try to learn how to do that, and then try adapting "by hand" C examples into Rust examples.

Comment: Well, of course I could try to interface directly with the C code from e.g. esp32-cam, but my goal is to achieve this as far as possible in rust. I want to dive more into the depth of the ESP and rust on it. Most of the other parts I have already running: SCCB communication, clock control and so on...
Or did you mean something else with 'translate'? It sounds a bit like adapting C to rust...

Comment: @Questmaster I had to do something similar a while back. What we ended up doing was using bindgen to generate Rust function stubs. Afterwards we went function by function and copied the c implementation into each function then translated it line by line. After we had it working in rust, we then went back and began switching pointers to references where possible and removing unsafe code. Once you get deep enough into the library you end up finding whatever the magic parts are which actually perform the tasks you need. You may need to dynamically link those parts.

Comment: @Questmaster What I meant is: Rust is completely capable of interacting with interfaces that think they are talking with a C programming language. In that sense, it is possible (although I don't know if it's the easiest way) to "mimic" the C code in Rust, that is, use Rust FFI capacities to directly translate C examples into Rust examples. The idea is not to write code in C, it is to "generate" by hand Rust examples (of which there seems to be a lack of) from the C examples (of which there seems to be plenty of).

Answer (score 1):

It won't be easy, but you can access registers in Rust 1.59+ using `asm!`. You will need to figure out which specific registers each value is bound to. I'm not familiar with Riscv32 so this may or may not be an actual register.

```rust
let x1_register: usize;

unsafe {
    // Read register to variable
    asm!("mov {0}, x1", out(reg) x1_register);
    // Write register from variable
    asm!("mov x2, {0}", in(reg) x1_register);
}

println!("x1_register: {:?}", x1_register);
```

Though to be honest, I'm not sure if it is actually changing any CPU registers. It seems likely based on this [header](https://gitcode.net/mirrors/espressif/arduino-esp32/-/blob/6e47e18a1b6f18d5f0b9b21eba2a202ee30601ef/tools/sdk/esp32s2/include/soc/esp32s2/include/soc/i2s_struct.h) I found that it may just be configuring some data for an SPI (or similar) interface.

Comment: The ESP32 uses the Xtensa architecture not RiscV. Only the newest ESP32-C3 are RiscV. But I don't think that this makes a huge difference. The register addresses and values are documented in the datasheet.